# Shutting down a Windows Workstation Remotely (from Linux)

Tags: windows-7, remote-access

I have a system comprised of, let's say 10 Windows 7 Professional workstations, joined to a domain.

As part of an "emergency" system shutdown procedure, I'd like a mechanism of triggering a remote shutdown, from a Linux controller (which is in turn, a service orchestration tool).  The word "emergency" is in quotes because it's not *really* an emergency, but still need a mechanism other than simply telling the users to turn the workstations off.

So, I've looked at `psexec`, which is almost ideal, except only seems triggerable from another windows machine.  .. I suppose it's not impossible to have a windows server trigger the workstation shutdown procedure, but that's not ideal.

I gather one option is to install Cygwin, and OpenSSH, but frankly, that seems *bulky*.

What I'd like, ideally.. Is a program that runs as a service, with local (or domain) Administrator privileges, listening on a port, for a SSL-encrypted, RESTful API call like, `http://workstation:8888/admin/shutdown?key=secretsharedkey`.

Do I need to write something in C#.net, or is there a tool out there for cross-platform triggering of a shutdown of a windows workstation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using the `net` tool from the Samba package?

For instance:

```
net rpc shutdown -S workstation1 -U Administrator -w example.com
```

You may need slightly different command line options such as `-k` to authenticate with Kerberos; check the man page.

Comment: Ugh.  Samba.  I'd rather not if I can help it.  I'll see tomorrow, but. Ugh. Samba.

Comment: Works like a charm.  Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [winexe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinExe). It uses a RPC call to install a service on the target computer, and then uses this service to execute commands on it. You can specify the credentials, and the Linux server doesn't have to be a member of the domain.

Beware that it *is* based on the Samba code though ;)

Answer (score 0):

RPC is the way, but there is may be more setup to do, especially for Windows Vista, Windows 7 and further windows versions, to allow remote shutdown:

**A) Part of setup to do on Win7 machine:**

1) run "secpol.msc"

- in the program tree, open "Security Settings / Local Policies / User rights Assignment"
- Find the entry “Force shutdown from a remote system”
- Edit the entry, add the CONCRETE user that will be used for shutdown (ex: nouknouk)

2) Run regedit.exe as Administrator

- find HKLM/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Policies/System
- create a new registry DWORD(32) value named "LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy" and then assign it the value '1'

3) Setup remote registry service:

- open “cmd.exe” as administrator
- execute the two following commands:

  sc config RemoteRegistry start= auto

  sc start RemoteRegistry

**B) Part of Setup to do on linux machine:**

1) install the "samba-common" package:

It depends on your linux distribution, but for Debian and derivated (Ubuntu, Linux Mint, ...), the apt-get command can be executed like that:

apt-get install samba-common

2) To actually shutdown your windowsmachine from the linux one, run the following command:

net rpc shutdown -f -t 0 -C 'message' -U userName%password -I xxx.yyy.zzz.ttt

Where:

- '-f' means 'force' the shutdown (I think it's mandatory)
- '-t 0' is the delay before doing it (0 means 'right now').
- '-U user%password' is the local user and his password on the windows machine (the one that has been alloed to do remote shutdown in point A).
- '-I' is the IP address of the windows machine to shutdown.